# DROP TABLE not working?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I have tried relentlessly to drop a table, but it doesnt seem to work. It doesn't give me any error message, but it seems like its taking a long time (6+ hrs). The table has around 800K rows with two columns.

Additionally, I can't even access the table using [sequel pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) or through the command line interface. The sequel pro message says `Loading`, but it never loads and command line gets stuck in the command without any messags.

However, `DESCRIBE` command works with the table.

I have similar problem with another table that has fairly less number of rows at 1000+.

However, i have other tables in the database that works perfectly fine.

Are there any issues with this version of mysql (see below) or are there any other methods that will let me delete the table.

I am using MySQL 5.1.73 Source distribution

Comment: Can you access the problematic tables with MySql Administrator/Workbench? Maybe these tables have faulty files and need to be repaired/rebuilded.

Comment: Hmm.. i havent tried MySql Administrator/Workbench GUI, but havent been able to access it from sequel pro or through MySQL command line. I will try repairing it..

Comment: repairing it also got stuck, and didnt work.

Comment: I think the files are broken beyond the possibility to recover: the only idea I've got is to go in the folder where the database is stored (it's written in the my.ini file in the basedir= entry) and delete the files .frm - .MYD - .MYI of the tables you want to delete and then recreate (ex. with a script) the tables from scratch

Comment: Thanks @AlexF, I have a script for recreating the table, so no problem there.